# How to reverse group policies on local machine

Tags: windows, active-directory, registry, gpo

Is it possible to revert to default policies on my local machine that my AD forces me to have? It makes it impossible to develop on my local VM as they disable features I need to make it run properly. I have admin on the local machine.

Comment: See if your network admin has a group to remove group policy or enforce local policy. It is generally a tricky area though as group policy is there for a reason, i.e protect the network.

Comment: The organization is too large and congested for something like that to get through. I understand that you *shouldn't* do this, that risk is for me to take. I'm just wondering *if* it's possible besides me having to comb through it all to know what is/isn't the registry that is the problem.

Comment: You can remove policies from the registry but its a bit hit and miss, have a look in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies, you can see the policies in there and remove them, set the permissions on the Policies Key to read only after. If you need to revert back, open a command prompt and enter gpupdate /force log off and back in again and the policies should be back, (after you set back the permissions on the Polices Key)